# i am splitting the data into testing and training set, the error is 'Found input variables with inconsistent number of samples: [1000, 23486]'

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, python-3.6, data-analysis

my project is to classify the reviews as good or bad using nlp. i have imported the data and done the tokenisation, vectorisation using bag of words model. now i have to spilt the data into testing and training sets and i am getting an error saying "Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1000, 23486]"

My file has a column called Review Text and i want to classify the reviews as good or bad. i have attached the tsv file that i am using for this project. please do help me in correcting the error and any change in approach that i can do. i have attached the code here too.

My data file [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1m5yPYsvjBKYPFTqPrDayWgVLfzq6u_Ad)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import nltk
import matplotlib

dataset = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/a/Downloads/data.tsv", delimiter = "\t", quoting = 1)
dataset.head()

import re
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
corpus = []
for i in range(0, 1000):
  review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', str(dataset['Review Text'][i]))
  review = review.lower()
  review = review.split()
  ps = PorterStemmer()
  review = [ps.stem(word) for word in review if not word in 
  set(stopwords.words('english'))]
  review = ' '.join(review)
  corpus.append(review)

  from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
  cv = CountVectorizer(max_features = 1500)
  X = cv.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()
  y = df.iloc[:, 6].values

  from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
  X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)
```

Comment: Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: @FedericoAndreoli hey! so the last 2 lines of code " from sklearn.model_selection.....  "  this line is giving me the " found input variables with inconsistent number of samples"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem is that `X` and `y` must have the same dimensions.

If you want to use just 1000 reviews you can use the same `for` cycle and then, when selecting `y` you just do:

```
y = dataset.iloc[:1000, 6].values
```

Otherwise, if you want to use the whole dataset you must edit the first part of the cycle.